# Eshell - confusion about weird order of evaluation in Haskell on Windows

Tags: eshell

I have wasted several hours trying to fix simple Haskell program where I tried to ask the user to enter a string and then display it.
The program looks like that:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter something "
  entered <- getLine
  putStrLn ("You have entered " ++ entered)
```

After hours of chasing my tail and reading lots of Monad tutorials I have discovered that my program works fine in cmd prompt. Can you imagine my frustration at this point?

This SO question gave me a clue to try it in cmd: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361508/execution-order-with-not-what-i-expected?rq=1

Is it possible to fix eshell? If not what is the best way to develop Haskell on Windows with Emacs?

### Temporary solution

After a bit of experimenting I decided to start cmd.exe with a customised script that sets my environment for Haskell development. The following script starts my cmd:

```
set PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;%PATH%
set INCLUDE=c:/msys64/mingw64/include
set XDG_DATA_DIRS=c:/msys64/mingw64/share
set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig
set HASKELL_GI_GIR_SEARCH_PATH=c:/msys64/mingw64/share/gir-1.0

cd C:/Windows/System32/

cmd.exe
```

Using cmd sets my path correctly. I have tried a similar script that launches powershell, which gives me better autocompletion than cmd, but for some reason I can't make the PATH in powershell accept my script settings, other environment variables seem to be OK.

### Another option

Following one commenter's question this is the version that works with eshell on Windows 10

```
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a string"
  hFlush stdout
  ln <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Yo have entered " ++ ln)
```

Note the use of **hFlush stdout** after first printing that was causing problems.

Comment: Surprisingly, this code works just fine in `eshell` on GNU/Linux. I suspect your problem might be related to `cmdproxy.exe`.

Comment: "This SO question gave me a clue" - did you try the `hFlush` and/or `hSetBuffering` suggestions in the answer?

Comment: @npostavs - No, it was 3 AM when I found it, so I thought I'd have a break.

Answer (score 1):

I have found something that works with eshell on Windows 10.

```
import System.IO (hSetBuffering, stdout, stdin, BufferMode(..))

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
  putStrLn "Enter a string"
  ln <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Yo have entered " ++ ln)
```

I have found further suggestions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520885/haskell-default-io-buffering

So it is not an eshell problem, but GHCI tries to be clever and is confused by cmdproxy. Toxaris has said the following:

> The GHC runtime system tries to be clever when it chooses the default
>   buffering. If it looks like stdin and stdout are directly connected to
>   terminal, they will be line-buffered. If it looks like they are
>   connected to something else, they are block-buffered. This can be
>   problematic if you want to run a program with line-by-line input that
>   doesn't come directly from a terminal.

Comment: By the way, the reason it works on Unix-like systems is because they provide [Pseudoterminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal), which Windows lacks.